# Condors to space

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

What short story ends with all condors and eagles assembling and forming a cyclone-like vortex? Then, dissatisfied, they leave behind Man and Earth.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Please to provide as much detail as you can for story ID question. Include when you read the story or when it may have been published, cover art, characters, setting, etc. This will help our story-id experts help you.

Comment: The story was published prior to 1973 and appeared in a book.

Comment: Are you sure it was condors and eagles, specifically?